# If an SqlCommand is executed and times out, is the respective SqlConnection closed and/or disposed?

Tags: sql, .net-3.5, sqlconnection

If an SqlCommand is executed and times out, is the respective SqlConnection closed and/or disposed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have your SqlConnection wrapping in a `using` statement, you're still responsible for closing and disposing the connection (just like any other exception).

You could also use a `try/catch/finally` block:

```
try
{
    // Create and execute your SqlCommand here
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    // Catch the timeout
}
finally
{
    // Close and Dispose the SqlConnection you're using
}
```

But `using` is much cleaner and disposes automatically:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    // Do your work here.
    // The SqlConnection will be closed and disposed at the end of the block.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you still need to clean up after yourself. Using a using block will cause it to be disposed though:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    // ...  
}
```

Comment: No it isn't. (why do I need to have 15 characters!)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on that, but calling `SqlConnection.Dispose()` also invokes `SqlConnection.Close()`. So the using block is 100% effective.

Answer (score 0):

This should all be wrapped around a finally clause after the exception so that you are closing your connection and cleaning up any sql realated object resource.
Look at try / catch / finally and put the clean up code in your finally statement.